# How can I spawn items into a chest, using Command Blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Like the title states, I want to be able to spawn items using a command block, and have them placed into a chest.

And I don't want to replace the chest, I want it to just add my block into the chest.

Answer (score 4):

Do

`/replaceitem block <x> <y> <z> <slot (if you want to fill the 9th slot of an ender chest with something, change this to slot.enderchest.9)> <item> [data] [dataValue]`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
`/setblock ~ ~ ~ chest 5` or if it doesnt work try `chest 2 {Items:[{id:<item>,Slot:<slot>,Count:<how many>,Damage:0s}]}`

Comment: I tried to put as much of the commands in code formatting as I could, but I don't know Minecraft commands well enough to say what is part of the command and what is instructions.

Comment: Use of numeric id is discouraged since it is obsolete/deprecated in latest versions of Minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just clone a hopper with a certain item that will point to the chest. The only problem I think is you can't really time it well (to me with this idea I filled the chest with one item per tick)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little roundabout way of looking at it but you could have your chest that already has items in it and attach a hopper that will feed item into it that chest. Then generate a command that will spawn a chest and feed those items of the spawned chest into your untouched chest with the hopper.

[Here is a link](https://minecraftcommand.science/prefilled-chest-generator) that will auto generate you a command that will generate a chest with custom items in it. With a Example:

```
/setblock ~1 ~ ~ chest 0 replace {
Items: [
        {
            id: "stone",
            Slot: 4,
            Count: 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, answers that contain nothing but links to other sites are not a good fit for our format. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/805262) question for more details.