# How to summon chest with button that can be placed on stone in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a problem I want to create a chest that will have a button inside and this button can be placed on stone block. Can someone give me the command? I was trying this: (No Error) It was placing chest with button but this button hasn't got option to place it on stone.

```
/setblock 776 74 363 chest 0 replace {
    Items: [
        {
            id: "stone_button",
            Slot: 13,
            Count: 1,
            CanPlaceOn: "stone"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you on Java edition?

Comment: @PeregrineLennert Yes

Comment: Then I recommend combining [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204723/how-can-i-spawn-items-into-a-chest-using-command-blocks?rq=1) and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/228524/how-do-i-give-myself-an-item-that-can-only-be-placed-on-a-block-with-a-certain-d?rq=1) into a single command

Comment: Or maybe edit your question into one asking about spawning a chest, with items in it.

Comment: @PeregrineLennert I was trying to combine this but when I did this it wasn't working. Can you do it for me please?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the command you were using and what error you were getting?

Comment: @PeregrineLennert Look on question.

Comment: I unfortunately can't help you much, but it might be that you have the button syntax wrong, I'm not sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tag a named item on the ground](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281764/how-do-i-tag-a-named-item-on-the-ground)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate of something that doesn't really ask the same, but the answer there tells you where to put the tag.

Comment: The dupe target has been closed for being unclear, it might be better to provide an answer on this question instead, as this question is more easy to understand. Other Q might then be set as Dupe of this one.

Comment: Given that the proposed dupe target is closed and has 1 pending delete vote, I am strongly against closing this question as a duplicate.

Comment: The linked question also doesn't really answer this question.  Yes, someone that has some experience can glean the answer to this question from that answer, but it isn't a straight path from one to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your command.

```
/setblock 776 74 363 chest 0 replace {
    Items: [
        {
            id: "stone_button",
            Slot: 13,
            Count: 1,
            CanPlaceOn: "stone" // specifically, this line
        }
    ]
}
```

## 1

The `CanPlaceOn` tag syntax specifies that it accepts an *array* of strings:

```
{CanPlaceOn:[
    "<ID>",
    "<another ID>",...
]}
```

(Note the pair of square brackets.) Therefore, it is necessary to enclose the block ID(s) in `[]`.

## 2

The `Item` tag syntax is as follows:

```
{Item:{
    id:"<ID>",
    Damage:<int>,
    Count:<int>,
    tag:{
        <Item NBT data here>
    }
}}
```

The syntax specifies that you need to put NBT tags of the item within the `tag:` tagname. Since `CanPlaceOn` is an NBT tag of an item, you need to enclose it with `tag:{}`.

## tldr

The correct command is as follows:

```
setblock 776 74 363 chest 0 replace {
    Items: [
        {
            id: "stone_button",
            Slot: 13,
            Count: 1,
            tag:{
                CanPlaceOn: ["minecraft:stone"]
            }
        } 
    ]
}
```

This has been tested in a 1.11.2 singleplayer world.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can make items with special features on them What you have to do is create the button and make it place on stone and then put the button in the chest